# How do you get Jinja templates into spinnaker/echo for webhook processing?

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker, azure-container-registry, spinnaker-halyard

I have Spinnaker 1.10.5 deployed to Azure Kubernetes Service using Halyard.

I am trying to get [Azure Container Registry webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-webhook) to trigger a pipeline. I found that [you can set up echo to allow artifact webhooks](https://github.com/spinnaker/echo/pull/197) using an `echo-local.yml` like this:

```
webhooks:
  artifacts:
    enabled: true
    sources:
    - source: azurecr
      templatePath: /path/to/azurecr.jinja
```

However, I'm stuck on the `templatePath` value. Since I'm deploying with Halyard into Kubernetes, all the configuration files get mounted as volumes from Kubernetes secrets.

**How do I get my Jinja template into my Halyard-deployed echo** so it can be used in a custom webhook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Halyard 1.13 [there will be the ability to custom mount secrets in Kubernetes](https://github.com/spinnaker/halyard/pull/1110)

Create a Kubernetes secret with your Jinja template.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: echo-webhook-templates
  namespace: spinnaker
type: Opaque
data:
  mytemplate:  [base64-encoded-contents-of-template]
```

Set the `templatePath` in the `~/.hal/default/profiles/echo-local.yml` to the place you're mounting the secret.

webhooks:
  artifacts:
    enabled: true
    sources:
      - source: mysource
        templatePath: /mnt/webhook-templates/mytemplate

Add the mount to `~/.hal/default/service-settings/echo.yml`

```
kubernetes:
  volumes:
  - id: echo-webhook-templates
    type: secret
    mountPath: /mnt/webhook-templates
```

Since Halyard 1.13 hasn't actually been released yet, I obviously haven't tried this, but it's how it *should* work. Also... I guess I may be stuck until then.